# How to save same triples in Virtuoso with different context

Tags: virtuoso, triplestore

I have a knowledge base in Virtuoso. I know we can save named graphs in Virtuoso in format of

```
context { subject predicate object ...}
```

I want to know when we extract same triple (`subject predicate object`) from different contexts (for example, different web pages in Wikipedia or a news website), is it reasonable to save the same triples in different contexts? What's the best solution in Virtuoso to store same triples from different origins?

Comment: Not related to Apache Jena. Tags removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the same triple values from different source then yes best way to do that is to save in different named graphs to act as containers such that they can co-exist in the Quad Store ...