# Save extra information for triples in virtuoso

Tags: virtuoso, triplestore

I am extract some triples from plain texts and I want to save them in a triple store like Virtuoso. The extraction algorithm gives us some extra information about each triples (e.g. precession, source of extraction, time and ...)
What's the best solution to store such data? Is using triple stores a good solution? Or a hybrid storing?

Comment: Not related to Apache Jena. Tags removed.

Comment: Possibly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437276/how-to-save-same-triples-in-virtuoso-with-different-context

Comment: I think two questions are different :-)

Comment: This question is much the same as the other. Optimal solution is to create a Named Graph (a/k/a _context_) for each source of triples, store those triples in the Named Graph (so they become _quads_), and then describe that Named Graph with the extra info (a/k/a _metadata_). The [Virtuoso Sponger](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSponger) does this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Virtuoso Sponger.

Comment: @TallTed about _store those triples in the Named Graph (so they become quads),_ we have meta data for each **triples** not for each **sources**.

Answer (score 1):

A Named Graph can hold a single triple, and so you could have metadata about that Graph's content.

Alternatively, you could use a form of *reification* to treat each triple — each *statement* — as an entity, and say something like (in very fake Turtle) —

```
{ _:triple1  
                       a   _:Statement
            _:hasSubject   <subject>
          _:hasPredicate   <prdicate>
             _:hasObject   <object>
         _:hasPrecession   <precession>
             _:hasSource   <source>
     _:hasExtractionTime   <time>
}
```

Comment: As a elite in triple stores, are you recommend this method (based on performance effects). An idea is saving regular triples in a store and data store by this solution (reification) in another store.

Comment: StackOverflow is not suited for conversation, so this thread should be taken elsewhere. As it stands, you're not providing enough information — about goals, needs, starting points, etc. — for good advice from anyone. Effects on performance vary with usage. I cannot say much about what effects *you* would see, without knowing *much* more about your usage.